# How to find file size in javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a fileupload control, I want to validate the size of the file to 50kb before the done button is clicked.

I did some research on the internet and got this code

```
<script>
   function A() {
      var oas = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
      var d = document.a.b.value;
      var e = oas.getFile(d);
      var f = e.size;
      alert(f + " bytes");
   }
</script>
```

I am using IE9 but this code is not working for me.
I am getting error on the line

```
var oas = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
```

How to solve this error?

Comment: try this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484303/get-size-of-file-requested-via-ajax

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach, i think it's much more user friendly.
It also prevents you from many browser / ActiveX related problems.

http://codes.codedigest.com/CodeDigest/65-File-Size-Validation-in-FileUpload-control-in-ASP-Net.aspx

Answer (score 0):

ActiveX need to be enabled in your browser safety setting, did you check it?