# Limit the size (bytewise) of an image loaded with the <img> tag

Tags: html, image

The initial problem: I want that the users of my future webserver can use an avatar.
The initial solutions (and their problems)

- Let the user upload his own image and save it

  - the pro here is that I might limit from the start the size of the image
  - the problem, instead, even if no one seems to care too much, is legal: not sure how it works in other countries, but here you might be considered liable for what you store on your hdd, in some cases (which I won't list, but that you might guess). This means that if someone uploads an illicit image as his avatar on your server and then this is reported to the authorities, you might find yourself in some kind of trouble, which, depending from the examining magistrate, might easily lead to the server going under requisition for months, for "further investigations".
- And here we came with the second idea: let the user define and save a link to an image, for his avatar

  - pro: legally safe
  - cons: what if the user defines a link to a 100MB image, which then all the users might be forced to download to see the page?

So the question is: is there a way to "say" to the browser that when it sees:

```
<img src='http://external.jpg' ...>
```

external.jpg size is supposed to be limited to, say, 100KB? And to drop the loading of it, if it goes over that size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this function you can get the file size and determine what to do from there. Also you can use an API like Clarifai to check for illicit content if you want to store it on your HDD.

```js
function get_filesize(url, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("HEAD", url, true); // Notice "HEAD" instead of "GET",
                                 //  to get only the header
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == this.DONE) {
            callback(parseInt(xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Length")));
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
}

get_filesize("URLHERE", function(size) {
    alert("The size of foo.exe is: " + size + " bytes.");
});
```

Source: [Ajax - Get size of file before downloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17416274/ajax-get-size-of-file-before-downloading)

Comment: Anyway, as a side note for whoever will find himself in a similar problem: it seems that either some servers don't use headers or they don't implement content-length. Indeed this solution works in some cases (for example, for me it worked for all the wikimedia commons images that I tested) but it doesn't work in a lot of other third-part-servers cases (and at that point it returns a NaN as size).