# Get file size without downloading it using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

Suppose there's a file on the server: https://cdn.lr-in.com/LogRocket.min.js

How can I see the file size (preferably in KB) without downloading it?
Code snippet should be executable in chrome dev tools so no node.js code, please.

Unfortunately [Is there a way to display the size of a file without downloading it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56137006/is-there-a-way-to-display-the-size-of-a-file-without-downloading-it) doesn't provide a reliable solution as there's no requirement that the Content-Length header is present in the headers of responses to HEAD requests.

From [Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP/1.1): Semantics and Content (HEAD)](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7231.html#HEAD)

> The server *SHOULD* send the same header fields in response to a HEAD request as it would have sent if the request had been a GET, **except that the payload header fields ([Section 3.3](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7231.html#payload)) *MAY* be omitted**

The Content-Length header is one of these payload headers and there is no requirement to include it in HEAD responses (although, if it is included it must be correct.)

As you can see, the Content-Length header is not returned for this request!

```js
fetch('https://cdn.lr-in.com/LogRocket.min.js', {method: 'HEAD'})
  .then((result) => {
    for (let key of result.headers.keys()){
      console.log(`Header: ${key}`);
    }
  });
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56137006/is-there-a-way-to-display-the-size-of-a-file-without-downloading-it

Comment: Did a quick test and the that duplicate doesn't always work as there's no gurantee that the Content-Length header will be present although it _SHOULD_ be.

Comment: Yeah, [docs](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7231.html#HEAD) say that the payload headers (incl. Content-Length) may be ommited for HEAD requests. Using HEAD request is not reliable. Don't know if you're going to find an answer to this though

Comment: that's okay if there's no working solution for now but let's keep the question open so if someone ever knows a workaround they can help

Comment: I don't see how it can ever be possible without the header because only the server can know the size (sometimes even the server doesn't know it, by the way) and so if it doesn't tell you, there can't be any way for you to find out.

Comment: "I don't see how it can ever be possible" that's a very strong statement. Anyway, how do browsers know the file size when they just initiate downloading a file? is there a way in js to initiate a download to get the file size and then cancel the download process.

Comment: A browser knows because they get the size from the header of the request they use to download the file (assuming `Content-Length` is even set, because a browser won't know either if `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` is used).