# How to get content-transfer [size] information like in devtools network tab?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to get the content-transfer size like in chrome devtool network tab through chrome extension API but it doesn't have events for this.

[image: Chrome Devtool]

Also checked [webRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) API.

Answer (score 1):

#### Low-level precise approach

DevTools itself uses CDP (Chrome DevTools Protocol) events like [Network.responseReceived](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#event-responseReceived) and its `encodedDataLength` field ([source](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:third_party/devtools-frontend/src/front_end/sdk/NetworkManager.js;l=350;drc=b8e8ad564da3081c6e3cf30e192fc93682b3d089)).

It can be used in an extension via [chrome.debugger](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger) API:

- attach the debugger to the tab
- navigate it to the URL or call [chrome.tabs.reload()](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-reload)
- send debugger command `Network.enable`
- register an event listener for `Network.responseReceived`
- detect the moment the page is loaded by using a sliding timeout aka [debounce](https://www.google.com/search?q=debounce)

An annoying side-effect is that Chrome shows a warning in all tabs when the debugger is used by an extension. If you need more info, search for `chrome.debugger` examples yourself ([here's](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:debugger) a few official ones) and inspect the source code of devtools.

#### Content-Length approach

Another approach is to use `Content-Length` HTTP header but it's not guaranteed to be present on all responses: [here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38041827) that you can further enhance with a check for `fromCache` field that's provided in a separate [onCompleted](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#event-onCompleted) event.