# How to show linked file size and type in title attributes using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, xhtml, accessibility

For example:

Before

```
<a 
target="_blank" 
href="http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/reader_overview.pdf">
Adobe Reader JavaScript specification 
</a>
```

Because the file is PDF the title should be `title="PDF, 93KB, opens in a new window"`

```
<a
title="PDF, 93KB, opens in a new window" 
target="_blank" 
href="http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/reader_overview.pdf" >
Adobe Reader JavaScript specification
</a>
```

Comment: To get the size for each document you would have to make a request for each document. It might be possible to use a HEAD request so that you don't have to download all content, but it's still a request for every link every time the page is viewed. Do you really want to do that?

Comment: @Guffa: That was my first thought.  I've actually attempted to HEAD request a third party server in the past and it's failed, so it might be possible not all servers respond to HEAD requests.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this, [Find size of file behind download link with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440723/find-file-size-with-jquery)

From that post you can do something like:

```
<a title="PDF, 93KB, opens in a new window"  target="_blank"  href="http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/reader_overview.pdf"
> Adobe Reader JavaScript specification </a>

$('a').each(function() {
  var request;
  request = $.ajax({
    type: "HEAD",
    url: $("#url").val(),
    success: function () {
      $(this).attr('title', request.getResponseHeader("Content-Length"));
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: but i need in title attribute.

Comment: +1 for answering the question. -1 coming for the question real soon if OP does not accept.

Answer (score 1):

Like duirlai said, take a look at [Find size of file behind download link with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440723/find-file-size-with-jquery).

Then the way you update your title with jQuery is like this...

```
$(function() {
  $("a[href$='.pdf']").each(function(i, obj) {
    var link = $(obj);
    $.ajax({
      type: "HEAD",
      url: link.attr("href"),
      success: function() {
        var length = request.getResponseHeader("Content-Length");
        if (!isNaN(parseInt(length))) {
          var fileSize = readablizeBytes(length);
          link.attr("title", "PDF, "+ fileSize  +", opens in a new window");
        }
      }
    })
  })
});

// From http://web.elctech.com/2009/01/06/convert-filesize-bytes-to-readable-string-in-javascript/
function readablizeBytes(bytes) {
  var s = ['bytes', 'kb', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB'];
  var e = Math.floor(Math.log(bytes)/Math.log(1024));
  return (bytes/Math.pow(1024, Math.floor(e))).toFixed(2)+" "+s[e];
}
```