# Javascript prevent form submit when over limit

Tags: javascript

I follow the suggestion from [Find size of file behind download link with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440723/find-file-size-with-jquery/4676024#4676024) for the file size checking and added `return false;` to prevent form submission, but **failed**. The code as following:

```
 function findSize() {
  var fileInput = $("#loadfile")[0];
  if (fileInput.files[0].fileSize > 1048 ) {
    alert(fileInput.files[0].fileSize);
    return false;
  }
 }

<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="form-submit" onclick="findSize()" />
```

How do I prevent form submission when file size over limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

putting you check in the `onsubmit` of the form instead of the `onclick` of the submit-button should solve this.

Comment: I tried the onsubmit but still the submission go through. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I should have put the onsubmit on the form instead on the button. It works now! Thank oezi.