# Fileupload - Retrieve File information before file loaded onto the webserver

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

How can I retrieve file information (size of file) before it is uploaded to the webserver?

I would like to create a multi file upload.  I have it working in JQuery but I would like to know the size of the files to set a limition by summing up the total the file sizes together.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find file size with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440723/find-file-size-with-jquery)

Comment: @Tim no, your´s is getting filesize of a file on a server, this one is aasking for one at client side

Answer (score 1):

[SWFUpload](http://demo.swfupload.org/Documentation/) has a File Object which provides it, though I don't know how well that's going to complete with your own code if you're writing your own multi-upload. If nothing else, you can look at the source and see how they're doing it, though they may be using the Flash interface for that.

Comment: Thank you but would like not to depend on flash plugin.

Comment: Well, I'm not 100% sure that that part comes from the plugin, so it might be worth a few minutes to look at the source. It might give you some good ideas in any case.