# How to get size of uploaded file in IE8,9 using Javascript or jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have tried a lot but did not find any way to solve my problem.

How to get size of uploaded file in IE8,9 ?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440723/find-file-size-with-jquery

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use Active X as those versions of IE do not support the HTML5 File API. I found a code snippet on the web that does that.

```
function getSize()
{
    var myFSO = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    var filepath = document.upload.file.value;
    var thefile = myFSO.getFile(filepath);
    var size = thefile.size;
    alert(size + " bytes");
}
```

Refer [this](http://www.kavoir.com/2009/01/check-for-file-size-with-javascript-before-uploading.html) for details.
Also take a look at the Remarks Section in the API Reference of IE for |input type=file|  [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535263%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).