# Get file size in Internet Explorer 8 and 9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I want to detect the file size before uploading it to the web. I got a java script from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601455/how-to-check-file-input-size-with-jquery) which is working well in Internet Explorer 10 and other browsers.

But I have most of the customers who are working with Internet Explorer 9 and Internet Explorer 8.
For that also I got a code form [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11735671/how-to-get-size-of-uploaded-file-in-ie8-9-using-javascript-or-jquery)

But the problem with that is It requires “Initialize and script ActiveX controls not marked as safe for scripting.”  to be enabled and also pops up to click on ok when the function is called. This method is not suitable for my requirement.
So is there any other methods to get file size in Explorer  9 and Internet Explorer 8 without any extra settings from user end ?

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So is there any other methods to get file size in Explorer 9 and Internet Explorer 8 without any extra settings from user end ?

No. That's why the [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) (what you're presumably using on IE10+) was created, because prior to that the only way to do it was ActiveX controls, signed Java applets, or Flash. So to do it on browsers that [don't support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi) the File API, you need to use...ActiveX controls, signed Java applets, or Flash, all of which will carry that kind of warning if they're going to be allowed to interact with the user's file system.