# How to know the size and file extension?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, php-5.3

On the page have a link to the file:

```
<a href="file.doc">File</a>
```

Next to the link should automatically show the extension and file size. Example: [File](http://file.doc) (DOC, 15 KB)

How to do it?

I found this documentation:

[How to have jQuery restrict file types on upload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651700/how-to-have-jquery-restrict-file-types-on-upload/651735#651735)

[Find size of file behind download link with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440723/find-size-of-file-behind-download-link-with-jquery/1440804#1440804)

but don't know how to unite them and show

**UPD**
okay, how to know the file extension?

Comment: How can you access the file from the enviroment where you write your html. Do you have PHP, .NET, JS envoriment?

Comment: @user237329 yes I have... heard that it is possible to do using PHP

Comment: Try this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_fileupload_files)

Comment: @KiRa a great example, it is possible to do for link to do this? I in js not BOM-BOM (sorry for my english)

Comment: What do you mean by `it is possible to do for link to do this` ?

Comment: @KiRa this example shows before downloading a file, and I need to be near the link showed

Comment: You mean after the file uploaded you need to determine the file size?. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @KiRa no.. I have a link to the doc file, I want to display фаеук to the link that is a doc format

Comment: You mean something like this `http://file.doc/ (file size and file extension?)`

Comment: @KiRa yesss)))) that is exactly what I want to do

Comment: @KiRa Have you any ideas? =(

Answer (score 0):

If you can determine that information ahead of time, you can use data attributes to tag the link and then display the extra content via CSS :after selector and `content: attr(data-size)`, etc.

If you can't, I think the links would need to be absolute file system links and you could do an Ajax HEAD request on the path to grab the content-length header, do some basic math, and add the relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 fie api supports to check the file size.

You may use the following code to check the file size as soon you upload the file.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
<output id="list"></output>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
<script>
  function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    // files is a FileList of File objects. List some properties.
    var output = [];
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
      output.push('<li><strong>', escape(f.name), '</strong> (', f.type || 'n/a', ') - ',
                  f.size, ' bytes, last modified: ',
                  f.lastModifiedDate ? f.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString() : 'n/a',
                  '</li>');
    }
    document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>';
  }

  document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
</script>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shishirmax/6364pvsh/)

[Read More Here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/)

Comment: Thanks, but i need this: something like this http://file.doc/ (file size and file extension?)

Comment: Please look at the fiddle, you may change the display type in the javascript code . Currently it display the information like [tb.jpg (image/jpeg) - 21657 bytes,]

Comment: and you can show without downloading the file... let's say the link to the doc file, the script recognizes his size and extension