# How to get file size from url using jquery

Tags: jquery

```html
<a href="files/doc_downloads/governance_docs/Whistleblower_and_Complaint_Policy.pdf" target="_blank" class="ModuleHeadlineLink">
  <span class="ModuleHeadline">Whistleblower and Complaint Policy</span> filesize
</a>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1440804/1719752

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about your application in  details but I have written a small one for my application to get the file size without downloading :

```
  var req;
  req = $.ajax({
    type: "HEAD",
    url: $("#url").val(),
    success: function () {
      alert("Size is " + request.getResponseHeader("Content-Length"));
    }
  });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You wrote it?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/1440804/1719752

Comment: Yes, i have it in my application. You want my github url ?

Comment: Just because it's in your github, doesn't mean you wrote it. If that's how it works, I'm the author of jQuery and Wordpress

Comment: Excuse me! don't forget. I'm the author of PHP!. dont' mess with me!