# How to get file size of a remote mp3 using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, mp3, html5-audio

I'm looking for a way to read a MP3 that's hosted remotely. I found something ([How to get file size from url using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43178676/how-to-get-file-size-from-url-using-jquery/43178721)) that can read it without downloading:

```
var req;
req = $.ajax({
type: "HEAD",
url: $("#url").val(),
success: function () {
  alert("Size is " + request.getResponseHeader("Content-Length"));
}
});
```

But I'm having difficulty getting it work with my code. What I'm trying to do is that when you click on button, it gets the file size of a remote MP3 and save the data to a `div`.

Here's what I've gotten so far:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#btn').click(function() {
    var audio = $("#audio-1")[0];
    var request;
    $("#duration").html(audio.duration);
    
    request = $.ajax({
      type: "HEAD",
      url: $("#audio-1").val(),
      success: function() {
        $("#size").html(request.getResponseHeader("Content-Length"));
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Duration: <div id="duration"></div>
Size: <div id="size"></div>

<button id="btn">Click</button>
<audio id="audio-1" src="https://media.acast.com/dth/weekinreviewfortheweekof6-21-21-dth/media.mp3" preload="metadata"></audio>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you're attempting to access the `val()` of the `audio` element, and they do not have a value. To fix this, get the `src` property instead:

```js
$(function() {
  var $audio = $("#audio-1");

  $('#btn').click(function() {
    $("#duration").html($audio.prop('duration'));

    $.ajax({
      type: "HEAD",
      url: $audio.prop('src'),
      success: function(data, status, request) {
        $("#size").html(request.getResponseHeader("Content-Length"));
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Duration:
<div id="duration"></div>
Size:
<div id="size"></div>

<button id="btn">Click</button>
<audio id="audio-1" src="https://media.acast.com/dth/weekinreviewfortheweekof6-21-21-dth/media.mp3" preload="metadata"></audio>
```

Note that you can access the `request` object from the third argument of the `success` handler function. The code is logically identical, just slightly cleaner as you avoid the need to declare the variable at the higher scope.

Comment: But also note that the audio WILL download to user's computer because it is in an audio tag

Comment: This is great! A good start for me but if the MP3 is over 98MB then it won't read the file.

Comment: You could potentially convert the AJAX call to listen for `headers_received` state instead of `done` (which means converting to a native `XMLHttpRequest` instead of jQuery) however the file will most likely still be downloaded by the browser.